# deleted_$taxonomy action is not calling

Tags: wordpress, hook

I want to call some function after my custom taxonomy was deleted. But the hook is not getting fired.

The hook is listed in WP [hook reference page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Taxonomy_and_Terms)

[image]

Anybody have the same issue?